# Using forceToLineString() with GDAL and Python?

Tags: python, gdal, shapely, linestring

For my script I'm looking for a method to convert a MultiLineString into a simple LineString.

Example:

MULTILINESTRING ((0 0,0 1),(0 1,0 2),(0 2,0 3,0 4))

==>

LINESTRING (0 0,0 1,0 2,0 3,0 4)

I found a GDAL-method called ["forceToLineString"](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometryFactory.html#adcae79ea28620e332a3d1df87f1180f3) but I don't know how to use it.
The way I tried does not work:

```
from osgeo import ogr
multiline = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiLineString)

line1 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line1.AddPoint_2D(0,0)
line1.AddPoint_2D(0,1)

line2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line2.AddPoint_2D(0,1)
line2.AddPoint_2D(0,2)

line3 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line3.AddPoint_2D(0,2)
line3.AddPoint_2D(0,3)
line3.AddPoint_2D(0,4)

multiline.AddGeometry(line1)
multiline.AddGeometry(line2)
multiline.AddGeometry(line3)

multiline.forceToLineString()

print multiline
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: How does it not work. What output do you get?

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
print(multiline.ExportToWkt())
'MULTILINESTRING ((0 0,0 1),(0 1,0 2),(0 2,0 3,0 4))'
line = ogr.ForceToLineString(multiline)
print(line.ExportToWkt())
'LINESTRING (0 0,0 1,0 2,0 3,0 4)'
```

It is easier with [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

```
coords = [((0,0),(0,1)),((0,1),(0,2)),((0,2),(0,3),(0,4))]
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString
line1 = LineString([(0,0),(0,1)])
line2 = LineString([(0,1),(0,2)])
line3  = LineString([(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)])
multiline = MultiLineString([list(line1.coords),list(line2.coords),list(line3.coords)])
# or 
coords = [((0,0),(0,1)),((0,1),(0,2)),((0,2),(0,3),(0,4))]
multiline = MultiLineString(coords)  
# result
print(multiline.wkt)
MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 0 1), (0 1, 0 2), (0 2, 0 3, 0 4))   
# convert to simple LineString (a MultiLineString is a list of LineStrings)
lines =[line for line in  multiline]
from shapely.ops import linemerge
print(linemerge(lines).wkt)
LINESTRING (0 0, 0 1, 0 2, 0 3, 0 4)
```